# overlaping QGraphicsItem-s hover events

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I have more QGraphicsItems on top of each other. How can I make hover event available for all items? Only the last added item (the one on the top) accepts hover events.

Thanks

Comment: How can you move your mouse on an item which is covered by another one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simulate those events, you "just" have to:

- reimplement `mouseMoveEvent` in a `QGraphicsView` or `QGraphicsScene` derived class,
- use `QGraphicsView::items(QPointF)` get the item list below the mouse
- create and send events, with `QGraphicsScene::sendEvent` whenever an item is added or removed from the list for all items but the one at the top of the stack (which is already handled).